# How do I subset this hacked together pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I subset rows 11 - 13?

I have a pandas dataframe with some hacked together data and I'm having the hardest time subsetting rows 11, 12, and 13. Essentially, I want to separate rows that start with "**dunntest**" and have **TRUE** in column 5 then put them into a new dataframe.

```
          Group         CL          CL1                 CL2        CL3  
0           Min      100.1        100.8               100.9      103.1   
1   1stquartile      100.5        101.1               101.4      103.3   
2        Median      101.6        101.4               101.6      103.4   
3          Mean      101.6        101.7               101.8      103.4   
4   3rdquartile      102.5        102.2               102.1      103.6   
5           Max      103.3        102.9               103.0      103.8   
6            CL        CL1          CL2                 CL3      CLDNA   
7     0.4165119  0.6244998    0.4415880           0.3500000  0.6489307   
8      dunntest       none     CL - CL1   0.469096846266772      FALSE   
9      dunntest       none     CL - CL2   0.378810361841698      FALSE   
10     dunntest       none    CL1 - CL2   0.429085199653927      FALSE   
11     dunntest       none     CL - CL3  0.0173616506762375       TRUE   
12     dunntest       none    CL1 - CL3  0.0382663620796246       TRUE   
13     dunntest       none    CL2 - CL3  0.0436908956580823       TRUE   
14     dunntest       none   CL - CLDNA   0.116215240987058      FALSE
```

If I do `print(df.loc[:, "Group"])` 
I get the first column of the entire data frame.

and when I do `print(df.loc[:, "Group" == "dunntest"])`

I get a KeyError: `KeyError: 'the label [False] is not in the [columns]'`

*Edit Using the column names is not reliable because they will always be different.

Comment: `df.loc[df.Group == "dunntest"]`

Comment: @piRSquared that is helpful, but how do I only get the rows with TRUE in the 5th column?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't providing a solution.  Only correcting the `KeyError`.  @jezrael has you taken care of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[(df["Group"] == "dunntest") & (df["CL3"] == 'TRUE' )])
       Group    CL        CL1                 CL2   CL3
11  dunntest  none   CL - CL3  0.0173616506762375  TRUE
12  dunntest  none  CL1 - CL3  0.0382663620796246  TRUE
13  dunntest  none  CL2 - CL3  0.0436908956580823  TRUE
```

If need select by 5. column use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) (python counts from `0`, so `df.iloc[:,4]`):

```
print (df[(df["Group"] == "dunntest") & (df.iloc[:,4] == 'TRUE' )])
       Group    CL        CL1                 CL2   CL3
11  dunntest  none   CL - CL3  0.0173616506762375  TRUE
12  dunntest  none  CL1 - CL3  0.0382663620796246  TRUE
13  dunntest  none  CL2 - CL3  0.0436908956580823  TRUE
```

Comment: df["CL3"] isn't reliable because that column name is always different

Comment: Sorry, I add solution for 5.column.

Comment: maybe include `df.iloc[:, 2].str.contains('CL3')`

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward approach will be:

```
df = df[(df["Group"] == "dunntest") & (df.iloc[4] == 'TRUE' )]
```